# Loop through multidimensional array and find matching values

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for a way to loop through a multidimensional array and with an if (or simular) find matching values if key master is true.

The array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [namn] => Vardagsrum
            [IP] => 192.168.1.232
            [rincon] => RINCON_000E58A64F1601400
            [rincon_live] => RINCON_000E58A64F1601400
            [master] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [namn] => Badrum
            [IP] => 192.168.1.137
            [rincon] => RINCON_B8E937580A5801400
            [rincon_live] => RINCON_000E58A64F1601400
            [slave] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [namn] => Kök
            [IP] => 192.168.1.134
            [rincon] => RINCON_000E58F8C9E001400
            [rincon_live] => RINCON_000E58A64F1601400
            [slave] => 1
        )

)
```

If i got a master => true (in this case vardagsrum) I would like the loop to match all slave => true rincon_live values against the masters rincon value.

I dont know if that makes any sense at all but if I got one or more masters, I want to check  the slaves rincon against the masters to see which slaves is connected to which master and after that do something.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error did you encounter? Can you post your code?

Comment: are all these items stored in the database ??

Comment: I'm not using a database, they are pretty much all dynamic from another function that builds this array.

Comment: Tomasz: I've got nothing that even comes close to what I'm after, quite new at coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to use 2 loops. One to build the structure and another to do something with it. Quick mockup(haven't written PHP in a while):

```
<?php
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (!isset($result[$item['rincon']])) {
        $result[$item['rincon']] = array(
            'master' => null,
            'slaves' => array(),
        );
    }
    if (isset($item['master']) && $item['master']) {
        // master
        $result[$item['rincon']]['master'] = $item;
    } else {
        // probably slave, might want to rewrite the else to an elseif
        $result[$item['rincon']]['slaves'][] = $item;
    }
}
?>
```

Now `$result` will contain an array with the rincon as a key and master/slaves in them like this:

```
<?php
$result = array(
    'RINCON_000E58A64F1601400' => array(
        'master' => array(
            'namn' => 'foo',
            'IP' => '127.0.0.1',
            ...
        ),
        'slaves' => array(
            array(
                'namn' => 'foo',
                'IP' => '127.0.0.1',
                ...
            ),
            array(
                'namn' => 'bar',
                'IP' => '127.0.0.1',
                ...
            ),
        )
    )
)
```

and I assume you know how to loop through that

Comment: Wow thanks, that did the trick. Never thought of going at it that way.